# How to merge multiple sets in Python with a generator expression?

Tags: python, set

I want to join multiple sets that are obtained from instances of a class. Below is an example of what I am working with and what I tried. Changing the class is not an option.

```
class Salad:
   def __init__(self, dressing, veggies, others):
      self.dressing = dressing
      self.veggies = veggies
      self.others = others

SALADS = {
   'cesar'  : Salad('cesar',  {'lettuce', 'tomato'},  {'chicken', 'cheese'}),
   'taco'   : Salad('salsa',  {'lettuce'},            {'cheese', 'chili', 'nachos'})
}
```

I want `OTHER_INGREDIENTS` to be `{'chicken', 'cheese', 'chili', 'nachos'}`. So I tried:

```
OTHER_INGREDIENTS = sum((salad.others for salad in SALADS.values()), set())
```

That gives me an error "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set' though.  How do I do this?

I would prefer to use Python 2.7 without additional imports if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function union from set:

```
OTHER_INGREDIENTS = set().union(*(salad.others for salad in SALADS.values()))
```

**Output**

```
{'chili', 'cheese', 'chicken', 'nachos'}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked and, while the other answer worked too, this one had the format that best matched our repo.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a set comprehension:

```
OTHER_INGREDIENTS = {
    element
    for salad in SALADS.values()
    for element in salad.others
}
```